# XServer: how to check who/what uses display:N

Tags: x11, xorg, x-server, xvfb

I have a strange situation. These are my commands and their outputs:

```
user@machine:~/Temp$ Xvfb :10 -screen 0 1024x768x16
_XSERVTransSocketINETCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
_XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) Cannot establish any listening sockets - Make sure an X server isn't already running(EE) 

user@machine:~/Temp$ Xvfb :11 -screen 0 1024x768x16
_XSERVTransSocketINETCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
_XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) Cannot establish any listening sockets - Make sure an X server isn't already running(EE) 

user@machine:~/Temp$ Xvfb :12 -screen 0 1024x768x16
started...
```

As you see dipslay:10 and display:11 are not free. However, in /tmp there are not files .x10-lock and .x11-lock. Besides, there are not =x10 and =x11 files in /tmp/.X11-unix.

How can I found out why displays 10 and 11 are not free?

Comment: Perhaps the ports are in use.  What does your Xorg.0.log say?

Comment: Are you using X forwarding with `ssh`? That would use displays 10 and upwards (listening on ports 6010, 6011, ...).

Answer (score 1):

You can find out with

```sh
lsof -i TCP:6010
```

As root, this will show any TCP listeners using the X11 display :10; change 6010 to 6011 for display :11, and so on; or use a range such as `TCP:6000-6020`.

You can similarly check for file socket listeners, if that is also a problem for you (you're only getting an error for the INET listener above, so it isn't - yet).  For example, if you run your Xorg with `-nolisten tcp`, you'll see it in the results of `lsof /tmp/.X11-unix/*`.

You can combine both:

```sh
lsof -iTCP:6000-6020 /tmp/.X11-unix/*
```

Comment: `lsof -i` doesn't seem to work for local connections to an Xorg server...? At least I can't find any hint in the output.

Comment: Hence my last paragraph - if your Xorg is running with the `-nolisten tcp` option, you'll want to check for processes listening on the UNIX-domain sockets, too - `lsof /tmp/.X11-unix/*`.

Comment: @TobySpeight on my debian system using xdm, lsof reports the user is `root` when I am logged in as my non-root user. Since I need to find which xauthority file I need to use, this isn't going to work for me. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Wyatt8740, that's totally unrelated - XDM runs the X server as the `root` user, so that is what you'd expect to see.  Sounds like what you want to do is to `ps -fHe` to see which other processes are started from the display manager, and examine their environments to see what `XAUTHORITY` they have set.  Better to ask that as a new question, rather than comment here, as there are other possible answers that may be useful.